# Django Slugify Not Showing Turkish Character

Tags: django

I wanna make business directory and i made category model here at the below.

```
class FirmaKategori(models.Model):
    kategori = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, null=False, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.kategori   
  
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('firma-kategori-ekle')  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.kategori, allow_unicode=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I made this, and if i allow_unicode=True, Forexample i made a category its name is Takım Tezgahları, became takım-tezgahları, but i want takim-tezgahlari

**Varyation 1:**
When i delete all allow_unicode=True tags, result is
Category name = Ulaşım Sektörü
Slug link: ulasm-sektoru

**Varyation 2:**
When i make all allow_unicode=True tags, result is
Category name = Ulaşım Sektörü
Slug link: ulaşım-sektörü

I want **ulasim-sektoru**

How can i solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved via replace but i have a still slug url problem...

Before solving, result is at the below.
[image]

And after i add this replace tag

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.kategori.replace('ı','i').replace('ş','s'), allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

[image]

Problem solved but, when i looked the link on the site, it has still

[image]

My category path is like this
path('kategori/slug:slug/', FirmaKategoriDetay.as_view(), name="firma-kategori-detay"),

How can i fix this.